# Append to form a List in a List

Tags: python, list, numpy, append

Does anyone know how to code in python in order to get the output R from P, C, and index by following the given rule?

Is it possible to use append? For example: perhaps a code similar to:

```
X.append(A[6]).append(B[1]).append(A[2])
```

If not, what could be the alternative? Thank you.

Here are the sets of integer.

```
P = [1, 2, 3, 4,5, 6]

C = [101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106]
```

P[1] refers to the first element in P = 1 (not python index)

Index

Storage_i is the index for each element from either P or C to form the R.
It always starts from P->C->P->C->P by taking the correspondence index from storage i.

```
storage_i = [[6, 1, 2],
 [6, 1, 3],
 [6, 1, 4],
 [6, 1, 5],
 [6, 2, 3],
 [6, 2, 4],
 [6, 2, 5],
 [6, 3, 4],
 [6, 3, 5],
 [6, 4, 5],
 [1, 2, 3],
 [1, 2, 4],
 [1, 2, 5],
 [1, 3, 4],
 [1, 3, 5],
 [1, 4, 5],
 [2, 3, 4],
 [2, 3, 5],
 [2, 4, 5],
 [3, 4, 5],
 [6, 1, 2, 3, 4],
 [6, 1, 2, 3, 5],
 [6, 1, 2, 4, 5],
 [6, 1, 3, 4, 5],
 [6, 2, 3, 4, 5],
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
```

Rule

```
for idx_i in storage_i:
q[idx_i] = np.remainder(idx_i,2)

    if idx_i ==n:
            A_cc = q[idx_i]*p[idx_i] + (1-q[idx_i])*c[idx_i]
        else:
            A_c = q[idx_i]*p[idx_i] + (1-q[idx_i])*c[idx_i]
            A_cc = q[idx_i]*c[idx_i] + (1-q[idx_i])*p[idx_i]
```

```
R =  [[P[6], C[1], P[2]]
[P[6], C[1], P[3]],
 [P[6], C[1], P[4]],
 [P[6], C[1], P[5]],
 [P[6], C[2], P[3]],
 [P[6], C[2], P[4]],
 [P[6], C[2], P[5]],
 [P[6], C[3], P[4]],
 [P[6], C[3], P[5]],
 [P[6], C[4], P[5]],
 [P[1], C[2], P[3]],
 [P[1], C[2], P[4]],
 [P[1], C[2], P[5]],
 [P[1], C[3], P[4]],
 [P[1], C[3], P[5]],
 [P[1], C[4], P[5]],
 [P[2], C[3], P[4]],
 [P[2], C[3], P[5]],
 [P[2], C[4], P[5]],
 [P[3], C[4], P[5]],
 [P[6], C[1], P[2], C[3], P[4]],
 [P[6], C[1], P[2], C[3], P[5]],
 [P[6], C[1], P[2], C[4], P[5]],
 [P[6], C[1], P[3], C[4], P[5]],
 [P[6], C[2], P[3], C[4], P[5]],
 [P[1], C[2], P[3], C[4], P[5]]]
```

Expected Result:

```
R =  [[6, 101, 2],
 [6, 101, 3],
 [6, 101, 4],
 [6, 101, 5],
 [6, 102, 3],
 [6, 102, 4],
 [6, 102, 5],
 [6, 103, 4],
 [6, 103, 5],
 [6, 104, 5],
 [1, 102, 3],
 [1, 102, 4],
 [1, 102, 5],
 [1, 103, 4],
 [1, 103, 5],
 [1, 104, 5],
 [2, 103, 4],
 [6, 103, 5],
 [6, 104, 5],
 [6, 104, 5],
 [6, 101, 2, 103, 4],
 [6, 101, 2, 103, 5],
 [6, 101, 2, 104, 5],
 [6, 101, 3, 104, 5],
 [6, 102, 3, 104, 5],
 [1, 102, 3, 104, 5]]
```

Comment: This should work if you were to index from 0 instead of 1. How are you inputting the rule `R`?

Comment: how the initial `R` is constructed? as you can't specify `P[6]` there, what is actually in `R` ?

Comment: What's `storage_i`? You don't seem to be using it at all. And why do you use the tag `numpy`?

Comment: The R is constructed from the q = index mod(2). The index starts from n, in this case 6. I add some information on the initial post.

Comment: @NicholasNicholas, the expected output does not seem correct: like the 1st item is `[6, 101, 3]` while it should be `[6, 101, 3]` for `P[6], C[1], P[2]` (as well as other subsequent 3d subitems ). Update your expected result

Answer (score 0):

Use the following approach (to rotatively select value from `[P, C]` on shifted index):

```
choices = [P, C]
R = [[choices[i % 2][j - 1] for i, j in enumerate(idx)]
     for idx in storage_i]

print(R)
```

---

```
[[6, 101, 2],
 [6, 101, 3],
 [6, 101, 4],
 [6, 101, 5],
 [6, 102, 3],
 [6, 102, 4],
 [6, 102, 5],
 [6, 103, 4],
 [6, 103, 5],
 [6, 104, 5],
 [1, 102, 3],
 [1, 102, 4],
 [1, 102, 5],
 [1, 103, 4],
 [1, 103, 5],
 [1, 104, 5],
 [2, 103, 4],
 [2, 103, 5],
 [2, 104, 5],
 [3, 104, 5],
 [6, 101, 2, 103, 4],
 [6, 101, 2, 103, 5],
 [6, 101, 2, 104, 5],
 [6, 101, 3, 104, 5],
 [6, 102, 3, 104, 5],
 [1, 102, 3, 104, 5]]
```